# Having trouble getting JSON object to work when passed to SCEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects, sceditor

I am using [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) and I am trying to set my own custom emoticons according to the emoticons option specified on [this page](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/options/).

So I called it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".sceditor").sceditor({
        // Other options
        emoticons: $.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json'),
        emoticonsRoot: '../../images/emoticons/default/'
    });

})
```

Then in my `emoticons.json` file I have this:

```
{
    dropdown: {
        ':)': 'emoticons/smile.png',
        ':angel:': 'emoticons/angel.png',
        ':angry:': 'emoticons/angry.png'
    }
}
```

However it is not working. I have checked the `NET` panel in my browser and I have confirmed it *is* fetching the `.json` file fine, however when I click to open the smiley window in the editor it is blank (all I see is the "more" link).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Json lint show above text in json file is invalid.

Try putting this in your json file

```
{
    "dropdown": {
        ":)": "emoticons/smile.png",
        ":angel:": "emoticons/angel.png",
        ":angry:": "emoticons/angry.png"
    }
}
```

I tried this in php

```
$a = '{
    "dropdown": {
        ":)": "emoticons/smile.png",
        ":angel:": "emoticons/angel.png",
        ":angry:": "emoticons/angry.png"
    }
}' ;
print_r(json_decode($a));
```

## Output

```
Array
(
    [dropdown] => Array
        (
            [:)] => emoticons/smile.png
            [:angel:] => emoticons/angel.png
            [:angry:] => emoticons/angry.png
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by your link.
The follows is my code:

```
$(function() {
        // Replace all textarea's
        // with SCEditor
        $("textarea").sceditor({
            plugins: "bbcode",
            style: "plugins/SCEditor/development/jquery.sceditor.default.css",
            emoticons: {
                // Emoticons to be included in the dropdown
                dropdown: {
                    ":)": "emoticons/smile.png",
                    ":angel:": "emoticons/angel.png"
                },
                // Emoticons to be included in the more section
                more: {
                    ":alien:": "emoticons/alien.png",
                    ":blink:": "emoticons/blink.png"
                },
                // Emoticons that are not shown in the dropdown but will still
                // be converted. Can be used for things like aliases
                hidden: {
                    ":aliasforalien:": "emoticons/alien.png",
                    ":aliasforblink:": "emoticons/blink.png"
                }
            },
            emoticonsRoot: "plugins/SCEditor/"
        });
    });
```

Above this, you may kown why your code is wrong.
Accross from [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), $.getJSON returns JQXHR,not a Json object. So, It is not possible to show your emoticons.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I need the JSON in an external file and not inline like the above.

Comment: @Brett Well, you can $.getJSON("url", function(data) { /** init sceditor */ });

Comment: I suppose that's an idea; no other way to get the JSON data without wrapping the whole thing like that?

Comment: @Brett Oh, you can use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON, and set $.ajax synchronous

Comment: Hmmmm..... I try and avoid using synchronous requests, I will see if I can come up with something else before going that path.

Answer (score 0):

As per WhiteWater's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778604/472501) the reason it wasn't working was because it was returning a `JQXHR` object and not a `JSON` object, so I had to work out how to get it to return a `JSON` object whilst the editor loading not being dependent on the emoticons existence.

So we have the solution below with credit to [jeremysawesome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296889/jeremysawesome) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30784433/472501) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781692/how-to-load-data-from-another-file-as-an-option-value-in-javascript-jquery):

```
// create a variable to store the results
var emoticons = false;

$.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json')
.done(function(result){
    emoticons = result;
})
.always(function(){
    // always initialize the sceditor
    $('.my-selector').sceditor({emoticons: emoticons}); 
});
```

This will load the emoticons but will *always* load the sceditor instance, even if the emoticons fail for some reason.