# How to load data from another file as an option value in JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Consider the below code:

```
$(".sceditor").sceditor({
    emoticons: // contents from another file here
});
```

I want to load another file which contains a `JSON` object as the value of the `emoticons` option.

I tried the below:

```
$(".sceditor").sceditor({
    emoticons: $.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json')
});
```

But that doesn't work because it `returns` a `JQXHR` object, not a `JSON` object.

To get the value I believe I would need to do something like:

```
$(".sceditor").sceditor({
    emoticons: $.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json', function(response) {
        // response is the JSON object
    })
});
```

But obviously that is not going to work as the `response` variable is inside the anonymous function and isn't returned to become the value of the `emoticons` value.

I know I could wrap the whole `sceditor` call inside the `$.getJSON` call, but I don't really want the whole code to rely on a successful call to the emoticons file.

I then thought about doing this above it:

```
$.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json', function(response) {
    var foo = response;
})
```

...but then how do I access `foo` outside the scope?

What is generally the best way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Wouldn't `emoticons: function() { $.getJSON('...', function(response) { return response; }); }` work? (just a thought here).

Comment: @D4V1D Tried it out but no go unfortunately...

Comment: Do you have an error? What is the output?

Comment: @D4V1D No error, but no emoticons loaded either; pretty much the same result as before where it loads the file successfully via the `NET` panel but doesn't show anything in the emoticon dropdown.

Comment: I would therefore suggest you to use global variable. Use your last solution but instead of `var foo = response;` use `window.foo = response` then `emoticons: window.foo,`.

Comment: Actually I think I came up with a solution based off your suggestion - just testing.

Comment: Well I tried this, but I think it just returns the JQXHR object: `var foo = (function() { return $.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json', function(response) { return response; }); })();`

Comment: I tried your global approach but it's showing as undefined. I think perhaps because of AJAX's `asynchronous` nature!?

Comment: Most certainly because of ajax being asynchronous.

Comment: What if you *don't* return `$.getJSON()` but rather return only `response` in your last approach?

Comment: Then it becomes `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `.done()` and `.always()` promise methods on the `jqxhr` object to accomplish this.

It sounds like what you want is to initialize the `sceditor` regardless of whether you have emoticons or not. However, if you are able to load emoticons then you want to use those.

Here is a quick solution showing how to use the promise methods to achieve what you want. Obviously you can expand and make this better, but this can serve as a starting point.

```
    // create a variable to store the results
    var emoticons = false;

    $.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json')
    .done(function(result){
        emoticons = result;
    })
    .always(function(){
        // always initialize the sceditor
        $('.my-selector').sceditor({emoticons: emoticons}); 
    });
```

And the requisite jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oLspfLby/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can define variable in outer scope, fill it in `getJSON` response function and use in further code

```
var foo;
$.getJSON('../../images/emoticons/default/emoticons.json', function(response) {
    foo = response;
});

$(".sceditor").sceditor({
    emoticons: foo
});
```